# Consulta JDBC - PreparedStatement - SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

Tengo que consultar en la base de datos mediante informacion que el usuario ingresa

Por ejemplo: si en mi bdd guardo registros de personas y el usuario quiere buscar aquellas con nombre 'Juan', ingresa Juan en un filtro que luego utilizaré en mi PreparedStatement.
El usuario además posee otros campos como por ejemplo la edad.
La cuestión es que el puede ingresar datos en el campo nombre y no en el de la edad o viceversa.

Mi PreparedStatement se vería algo asi:

```
PreparedStatement pstm = coneccion.prepareStatement("SELECT apellido,nombre,edad from tabla_personas WHERE nombre=? AND edad=?")
```

A la hora de setear nombre y edad, alguno puede ser null y por lo tanto quiero que ignore esa condición, por ejemplo, si el usuario no ingresa la edad, mi PreparedStatement equivaldría al siguiente:

```
PreparedStatement pstm = coneccion.prepareStatement("SELECT apellido,nombre,edad from tabla_personas WHERE nombre=?)
```

Como consigo esa 'omisión' en el WHERE? Tengo que armar las consultas por cada campo en el que se pueda omitir? Que en este ejemplo tendría 4 casos, por lo tanto 4 consultas diferentes

Comment: La solución que usé es armar el PreparedStatement en base a los datos que se tiene (concantenando strings, utilizando if else, es lo que queria evitar pero al menos me ahorro de hacer reiteradas consultas sql con sus respectivos try/catch)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar la clausula `OR` en vez de la clausula `AND`
por ejemplo en vez de decir

```
"SELECT apellido,nombre,edad from tabla_personas WHERE nombre=? AND edad=?"
```

Intenta

```
 "SELECT apellido,nombre,edad from tabla_personas WHERE nombre=? OR edad=?"
```

De esta manera si cualquiera de las condiciones se cumplen se efectuara la consulta, sin necesidad de que todas sean verdaderas, me cuentas si te funciono

Comment: Que debería setear en el PreparedStatement cuando los parametros son nulos?
Si el usuario no ingresa ningun parametro y yo quiero obtener entonces todas las tuplas de la tabla, que debería setear en los PreparedStatement?
Probé con poner setNull(index, Types.INTEGER) (en caso de no tener el parametro de la edad para ese ejemplo), pero la consulta se realiza como si el campo realmente es NULL en la bdd, cuando lo que quiero es omitir la condición.

Gracias